# Multiple Updates on difderent tables in mysql (Stored Pocedure)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, sql-update

I'm trying to make multiple updates on different tables in an stored procedure in MYSQL. But if one of these updates doesn't find the ID it will make a warnning or error.

So I thought to use IF ELSE but I don't know how to make it.

this is an example of the code in an stored procedure

```
be is an entrie parameter.
       update table1 set status = 2 where id_be = be;
       update table2 set status = 2 where id_be = be; 
       update table3 set status = 2 where id_be = be;
       update table4 set status = 2 where id_be = be;
       update table5 set status = 2 where id_be = be;
       update table6 set status = 2 where id_be = be;
       update table7 set status = 2 where id_be = be;
       update table8 set status = 2 where id_be = be;
       update table9 set status = 2 where id_be = be;
```

So, I need if the first update is successfull or true, leave de stored procedure if not,  continue to the anotherone.

I hope you can help me. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

So it works for 5 Tables. you can extend it.

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` PROCEDURE `setup`(IN be CHAR(200))
BEGIN
DECLARE countRow INT;

  UPDATE table1 SET STATUS=2 WHERE id_be = be;

  SET countRow = ROW_COUNT();
  IF(countRow =  0) THEN
    UPDATE table2 SET STATUS=2 WHERE id_be = be;
  END IF;

  SET countRow = ROW_COUNT();
  IF(countRow =  0) THEN
    UPDATE table3 SET STATUS=2 WHERE id_be = be;
  END IF;

  SET countRow = ROW_COUNT();
  IF(countRow =  0) THEN
    UPDATE table4 SET STATUS=2 WHERE id_be = be;
  END IF;

  SET countRow = ROW_COUNT();
  IF(countRow =  0) THEN
    UPDATE table5 SET STATUS=2 WHERE id_be = be;
  END IF;

 END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

**call it :**

```
CALL setup('xx');
```

Comment: sorry my mistake, be is not a string, is an entrie parameter,

Comment: i have change my answer